# Как сгенерировать все возможные графы по переданным вершинам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, graph

Пусть есть 3 (хоть 10) вершины графа.

как сгенерировать все возможные соединения этих точек при таком условии, что точки должны быть соединены все?

То еть, не может быть такого, что какая-то вершина без соединения с кем-либо.

Comment: Количество связных графов с 10 вершинами - 34496488594816. Я б не стал их все генерировать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужны все комбинации пар вершин:

```
from itertools import combinations

# вершины
nodes = list('ABCDEFG')

# ребра
edges = list(combinations(nodes, 2))
```

результат:

```
In [96]: edges
Out[96]:
[('A', 'B'),
 ('A', 'C'),
 ('A', 'D'),
 ('A', 'E'),
 ('A', 'F'),
 ('A', 'G'),
 ('B', 'C'),
 ('B', 'D'),
 ('B', 'E'),
 ('B', 'F'),
 ('B', 'G'),
 ('C', 'D'),
 ('C', 'E'),
 ('C', 'F'),
 ('C', 'G'),
 ('D', 'E'),
 ('D', 'F'),
 ('D', 'G'),
 ('E', 'F'),
 ('E', 'G'),
 ('F', 'G')]
```

---

Можно использовать специально предназначенную для работы с графами библиотеку [networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.complete_graph(nodes)
```

результат:

```
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, а как из этого образовать так же теперь всевозможные графы. Все-возможные ребра перебраны. Я просто теорвер уже позабыл

Comment: @АндрейПетров, дайте определение для `всевозможные графы`

Comment: Библиотека, конечно, решит мою проблему, но хочется понять это. Т.е хотя бы с помощью combinations перебрать, составить все возможные графы и разобраться с этим на уровне теорвера

Comment: @АндрейПетров, что значит все возможные графы?? Можете привести пример в вопросе для 3 или 4 вершин?

Comment: Ну есть три точки (S T A) , Я могу соединить точку S->T->A,А могу, например, S->A->T
Вот такие комбинации

Comment: @АндрейПетров, т.е. вы хотите найти все возможные маршруты для всех комбинаций пар вершин? Это совершенно другой вопрос, который имеет мало общего с вашим оригинальным вопросом. Задайте новый SO вопрос для этого...

Comment: @АндрейПетров, можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535898/5741205). По ссылке предлагают использовать модифицированный [поиск в ширину](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83)

Comment: @АндрейПетров, какая-то у вас "быссмысленно-беспощадная" задача! Хотя бы намекните зачем вам это? Обычно ищут кратчайший или наиболее длинный путь, но не все возможные пути...

Comment: Алгоритм 1-Штейнера Канга

Comment: Почему маршруты? Когда я говорю не о маршрутах. Ведь S->T->A и S->A->T это два разных графа. Если у точек графа фиксированное положение то стоимость при определенных соединениях может быть разной

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import permutations

nodes = list("abc")
print(*permutations(nodes), sep = "\n")
```

вывод:

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```

Comment: Это просто все варианты перестановок, графа тут не видать, если точек будет больше